# Running multiple programms in one shell

Tags: windows, shell

Is there a shell to run applications? I want to run multiple applications in the shell (from 1 to 5) and each window has its own position and size. That is, one application was at the top left, and the second at the top right, etc. Thanks in advance.

I have 2 exe, that i compiled in Unity3D on Windows. First is the Menu.exe, where i can input settings and second is actually game( lets call it games.exe). What i want. I want to launch my Menu.exe, input my settings, then press button "start" and launch a few copy of games.exe(lets say 4). And each copy must have unique name, position and size.

There is a video how it currently works
[video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B18ilfYUhU0iRkpCaF9mdXZQYlU/edit)
. When i press "Start" Unity run bat file which execute games.exe 4 times with delay 3 sec. It dont works on slow computer. And i cant set position and size of opened window via bat file.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to reinvent Windows or X11 - good luck

Comment: You can create ~/.xinitrc or you may create systemwide xinitrc.

Comment: I have a game, that i compiled in Unity3D. When game is started it rename title and set position and size. I run game via bat file. But i run each exe with delay to make this work and when exe running there begin screen flashes and it has bad looking. All i need is to run multiple exe and set size and position for each window.

Comment: Please add any clarification to the original question, not in the comments.  Context like platform (Unity3D on Windows) is a good example of that.  Next thing to add: what are the 5 applications, are they all part of the same game?

Comment: platform : Windows. there 2 apps, first - menu.exe . second - actually game.exe . I need to run 4 copy of game.exe simultaneously and place each copy in different position.

Comment: This is not related to unity. Why don't jyst create your software and internally divide the screen using windows or panels...

Comment: Windows can already do that. Just start multiple programs.